# Navigation Bar and envelope icon showing on splash screen

Tags: android, navigationbar, android-navigation, android-navigation-bar

I have a navigation drawer that is working fine on my app. I recently added a splash screen and it loads ok but a navigation bar is showing up along with an email icon on the bottom right.

[ScreenShot form Tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoSPL.png)

I have this on my manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    </activity>
```

How do I remove these unnecessary tab and icon on the splash screen?

I have this on my splashactivity Java:

```js
package widevalue.com.widevalueautoinc;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView tv ;
    private TextView tv2 ;
    private ImageView iv ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2) ;
        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv) ;
        Animation myanim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.mytransition);
        tv.startAnimation(myanim);
        tv2.startAnimation(myanim);
        iv.startAnimation(myanim);
        final Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Thread timer =new Thread(){
            public void run () {
                try {
                    sleep(5000) ;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

[image: After Floatingbar and Nav bar were gone.]

Comment: Can you please post your splash screen xml code?

Comment: Please share your splash activity's code as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove these unnecessary tab and icon on the splash screen?

The icon is called `FloatingActionButton`. remove the following code from splash activity `layout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

The `tab` is called `actionbar`. You can remove it using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` theme for `SplashActivity` in `manifest` file

Comment: Btw @Ali , how to I remove that white line border on the splash screen as shown on the screenshot after I followed your instructions? (attached the image on the question)